# Use ajax success html data to set width of div

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<script>
window.setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'ajax.php',
data:{action:'DisplayLevelMeter'},
success:function(html) {

$('#LevelMeterPercent').css('width', html);

}

});
}, 2000);    
</script>
```

I have a number coming through in the (html), I would like to use this number to set the div's width.

The success script does work, I can replace html with '400' and the width changes.

How can i use the html as like a variable for my new width?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: { action: 'DisplayLevelMeter' }
    }).done(function (html) {
        $('#LevelMeterPercent').css('width', html);
    });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: It appears to be using html as a number, it puts my width to half. Seen this before when trying different things.

Comment: hmm i think i know the problem, I need a % sign in with the width somehow.

got it: 
$('#LevelMeterPercent').css('width', html + '%');